# I am getting error after I tried to installed dependency by ng2-twitter on Twitter Integration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5, twitter-oauth

While working on my Application  , I tried to integrate twitter with my Application  using https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-twitter
After I have installed npm install --save ng2-twitter to my APPLICATION 
I am getting the following **error -**

I deleted node_modules from my Application and Again installed in using 
npm install but I am getting same error

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js 206:41-69
"export '__platform_browser_private__' was not found in '@angular/platform-browser'

WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js 71:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js 87:15-102
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/Users/user/Projects/Angular/samachar-dekho/node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/Users/user/Projects/Angular/samachar-dekho/node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends/jsonp_backend.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable' in '/Users/user/Projects/Angular/samachar-dekho/node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/http/src/backends'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Subject' in '/Users/user/Projects/Angular/samachar-dekho/node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/lang.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/symbol/observable' in '/Users/user/Projects/Angular/samachar-dekho/node_modules/ng2-twitter/node_modules/@angular/core/src/util'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I am also putting package.json file  from my Application below

```
{
  "name": "samachar-dekho",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-bootstrap-md": "^6.2.5",
    "angular-image-slider": "0.0.8",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "ng-simple-slideshow": "^1.2.5",
    "ng2-twitter": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-slick": "^0.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a dependency problem. Is ng2-twitter compatible with Rxjs version 6? My guess it is it may not be. There are some changes in Rxjs and how things are referenced. You could try and install rxjs-compat (npm i rxjs-compat --save)

Comment: thanks @TheCount but for now How I can , uninstall the previous dependency ,and  fix the error so that , my Application can for  now  in the way it was running previously ,

Comment: did you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Was facing same issue and then `npm i rxjs-compat --save` does the trick for me!